# JQuery event handler not firing after changing class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have the span, on click, toggle its classes between `.btn-warning` and `.btn-primary`. However, my code only works for the first click. Every click thereafter doesn't work.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-warning').on('click',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
    });
    $('.btn-primary').on('click',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="btn btn-warning" >Click me</span>
```

Comment: change your event handler to this 

$(document).on('click', '.btn-warning', function(){ // your code });

Answer (score 1):

Changing the class does not magically add the events that were previously added. You either need to unbind/bind the events once again, or use a generic onclick handler that knows how to handle it, or use event delegation.

All that code could be reduced to:

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning').toggleClass('btn-primary');
});
```

```css
.btn-primary { background-color: blue; }
.btn-warning { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="btn btn-warning" >Click me</span>
```

Comment: You don't need to `toggleClass` twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method because you're binding event to dynamically added class element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.btn-warning',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-primary');
    });
    $(document).on('click','.btn-primary',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-warning');
    });
});
```

---

Simply you may do like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".btn", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning btn-primary');
});
```